# Jquery website under problems

Tags: jquery

static.jquery.com is down so the jquery.com website CSS and js not available !!!

I hope all the sites that were linking their jquery from the static.jquery.com might be doing well or not?

I've checked the site availability but got the down answer too

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://static.jquery.com

Answer (score 1):

Use Google's. Much more reliable AFAIK: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

[More libraries here](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with online resources, maby you should consider using a script loader mechanism (such as [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/)) which can load scripts based on conditions.
Here's an example from the yepnope homepage:

```
yepnope({
  load: 'http:/­/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js',
  complete: function () {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
      yepnope('local/jquery.min.js');
    }
  }
});
```

This way, if the online resource is not available, you can load a local copy of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Download it local, only "issue" here is that users that have jquery in chache will have to load it again.

Comment: I would agree with you partially but gion_13's answer is better as it gives the user a chance to load the library from cache before defaulting to local (for a failsafe). The google hosted version shoul be close to 100% reliable - providing a local fallback accounts for the micropercent chance that google will be unresponsive.